# use fscanf() function in swift code

Tags: ios, swift

In objective c, I use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) to read stream from file and assign the value to variables:

```
int count;
char type[5];
fscanf(myFile, “count is %d, type is %4s ”,  &count, type)
```

I want to do the same thing in **swift** code, I tried:

```
//ERROR: Type annotation missing in pattern
//What type should I use for `count`?
var count
//ERROR: consecutive  statement on a line must  be separated by ‘;’
var type[5] : char
fscanf(myFile, “count is %d, type is %4s ”,  &count, type)
```

But I got  compiler errors showing above. What is the correct way to use `fscanf` in swift ?

If you know any swift way to achieve the same thing (without using `fscanf`), it would be great too!

Comment: Your first problem is that the variable declarations are completely invalid Swift code, so you might have a look at the first chapters in the Swift book again.

Comment: I read, but I don't know what type should I declare in my code. Also the 2nd error sounds weird. I need suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use Foundation framework solution for reading/writing file data. A sample code to read contents of files which I used in my app to stream file into NSData:

```
if let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "path/to/file") {
    fileHandle.seekToFileOffset(0)
    var data = fileHandle.readDataOfLength(5)
    var chars = [UInt8](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&chars, length: 5)
    fileHandle.closeFile()
}
```

In case you need read Int64 data from file at a specific location:

```
if let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "path/to/file") {
    fileHandle.seekToFileOffset(0)
    var data = fileHandle.readDataOfLength(500)
    var intFetched: Int64 = 0
    let location = 100 // start at 101st character of file
    data.getBytes(&intFetched, range: NSMakeRange(location, 8))
    println(intFetched.littleEndian)
    fileHandle.closeFile()
}
```

Comment: How to read the integer `count`? How many bytes I should read for `count`?

Comment: it depends size and endianness of integer. on a arm64 it's 8 bytes little endian. On arm v6/7 it's 4 bytes little endian.

Comment: After 1st `data.getBytes(&chars, length:5)`, if I call `getBytes(...)` again, does the pointer points to the place where it has read (i.e. 5) or reset automatically to position 0?

Comment: getBytes:length: will start from position 0 according to documentation. Use getBytes:range: instead.

Comment: I defined chars as array of UInt8. if you want read integer, simply define it as Int64 or Int32 and set length to 8 or 4 bytes accordingly. if file saves data as big endian. use Int.byteSwapped property to correct endianness or simply use .bigEndian/.littleEndian properties to get correct data. Please avoid using platform-dependent types when reading files.